# Is there a way to put the text of a QCheckBox above the icon?

Tags: pyqt4, qcheckbox

I have a gridlayout that holds a bunch of check boxes.  I wanted to add an image to the check boxes as well as some text.  The problem I am having is that the layout of a check box is left to right (check box, icon, text).

Is there a way to put the text above the icon?  Not sure if using a style sheet would work for this or not or even how that would look.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer :** In PyQt4. No, your can't do it.

**Why ?** I read source code of `QCheckBox` Qt4 (C++) [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/e7f7d1f20ed691a274dcf07801baa17f7a8aabf9:src/gui/widgets/qcheckbox.cpp#L170) and [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/e7f7d1f20ed691a274dcf07801baa17f7a8aabf9:src/gui/widgets/qcheckbox.cpp#L299). I saw it use default `QStyleOptionButton` to show check box, text and icon. It's use `drawControl` to draw all element in `QStyleOptionButton` by specified config in `QStyleOptionButton`. Also it have `LayoutDirection`. And layout direction in  `QStyleOptionButton`. I don't know in Qt4 C++ and inheritance it and swap direction icon. But in PyQt4, It's impossible to do it.

**Another way ?** : Yes, It have another way to solve but not directly. Your just create your own widget just like `QCheckBox` and disable icon in `QCheckBox` and make your own `QLabel` ot show your icon and set it with same `QLayout`.

Example;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class QCustomCheckBox (QtGui.QWidget):
    stateChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__ (self, text, parentQWidget = None):
        super(QCustomCheckBox, self).__init__(parentQWidget)
        self.customQCheckBox = QtGui.QCheckBox(text)
        self.iconQLabel      = QtGui.QLabel()
        allQHBoxLayout  = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.customQCheckBox)
        allQHBoxLayout.addWidget(self.iconQLabel)
        allQHBoxLayout.addStretch(1)
        self.setLayout(allQHBoxLayout)
        self.customQCheckBox.stateChanged.connect(self.stateChanged.emit)

    def setPixmap (self, newQPixmap, width = 48, height = 48):
        self.iconQLabel.setPixmap(newQPixmap.scaled(width, height, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))

    def pixmap (self):
        return self.iconQLabel.pixmap()

class QCustomWidget (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QCustomWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        allQVBoxLayout  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        firstQCustomCheckBox = QCustomCheckBox('First Check Box')
        firstQCustomCheckBox.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('1.jpg'))
        allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(firstQCustomCheckBox)
        secondQCustomCheckBox = QCustomCheckBox('Second Check Box')
        secondQCustomCheckBox.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('2.jpg'))
        allQVBoxLayout.addWidget(secondQCustomCheckBox)
        self.setLayout(allQVBoxLayout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myQCustomWidget = QCustomWidget()
    myQCustomWidget.show()
    sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```